# Swift 2 - Why is a UIButton not working in a view added as a child in another UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, swift2

I have a main `ViewController` where I load in its view another view from a second `UiViewController`.
The view from the second `UiViewController` loads fine however, when I try to create a button in that view the code is not fired. The `UiButton` from the second view is connected in the storyboard using `touch up inside`. Why is this button not fired?

MAIN `UiViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let newsPageVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("news_id") as! newsViewController

self.containerView.addSubview(newsPageVC.view)
}
```

SECOND `UiViewController`

```
@IBAction func ClosePreviewAct(sender: AnyObject) {

        print("close")
    }
```

Comment: check your iboutlet connection

Comment: I did they are connected fine. I have dragged the button to the second view controller and created a `@IBAction`

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine now.
The code was missing

```
self.addChildViewController(newsPageVC)
        newsPageVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Version for swift 3.0

```
self.addChildViewController(newsPageVC)
newsPageVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```